# Compact code vs More readability, why to prefere one or the other?

Tags: python

**The core of the question:**
Python offers the option to complete the same task using rather different syntax, and I would like to understand why one should chose more compact syntax over a more readable code.

**More in-depth description of the issue:**

Let's look at an example where we build an array containing  random numbers by using a common for loop and a more compact way to do the same.

1. The standard for loop method:

```
for j in range(4):
    stat_rolls.append(random.randint(1, 6))
```

2. Using List Comprehension:

```
stat_rolls = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]
```

I measured this 2 methods against each other for performance up too 10000 iterations and does not seem to be any difference in execution time.

Now lets expand the example a little by creating an array that contains same sized arrays  filled with random ints:

1. The standard for loop method:

```
for i in range(100):
    buffer=[]
    for j in range(4):
        buffer.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    stat_rolls.append(buffer)
```

2. Using List Comprehension:

```
stat_rolls = [[random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(100)]
```

As one could also predict , the list comprehension method is slightly better performing than the for loop approach but also here measurement shows a 9% to 10% better runtime (which means a tenth of millisecond in this case, which scales linearly).

There are other methods to write more compact code, I just addressed the List Comprehension case.

I would like to understand why one should prefer one style or the other since to my test seems like they have little to no performance difference but sacrifice code readability.

Comment: The small performance differences you're seeing are due to small number of cases (400).

Comment: for me list comprehensions are more expressive and easier to read.

Comment: Up to one million iteration there is still just 10% difference wich means 0,3 sec more on the loop method.

Comment: The short answer is "It depends, use whichever is clearer and more readable in context." Beyond that, I'm afraid Stack Overflow is expressly [not suited for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) open-ended, opinion-based questions. It would probably be a *better* fit on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but it may or may not be too open-ended for there too, I'm not sure.

Comment: Generally, I don't even consider performance unless I've profiled and determined a significant speed-up can be achieved compared to the rest of the program. There's another advantage of the comprehension you haven't addressed however, which is intermediary state. Using the comprehension `stat_rolls` is only ever in one state. It is impossible to access the variable until it is defined, and when defined it is completely initialized, vs with the traditional for loop, the variable can be accessed before it is fully initialized.

Comment: if it is simple and can be done in 2 for loop in list comprehension then go for that, other wise if it require functional call or some intialization or has many condition go for way 1